# Tutorial for performing Contrasts for MANOVA

Tags: manova, contrasts, hotelling-t2

#### Context

I have a multivariate dataset with a test group and three control groups.
I was thinking that the best way to determine if and how the test group differed from all of the control groups would be to perform a MANOVA, then perform contrast analysis between the test group and all of the control groups.

#### Main Question

I cannot seem to find a good description of how contrast analysis for MANOVA is performed.
Every tutorial/online class I can find, just talks about throwing the contrast into SPSS, or the univariate case.

- Can anyone point me to a good tutorial on contrasts for MANOVA?

#### Questions

- Is MANOVA with contrasts the appropriate way of answering my research question?
- Would it be better to perform repeated Hotelling's tests on the test group vs each control group, and just use a Bonferroni correction?

Comment: Check out Applied Multivariate Analysis by author Neil H. Timm. He has written multiple books on this. Mary A. Marion